# vuejs - How to pass variable to main js file and then iterate through?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, parameter-passing

I'm working in Laravel. What I want to do is to get the posts from the server and show them in view, however before that I wanted to set static array containing sample posts but my problem is that I can't access posts variable in app.js file when passing by `data(){...}` and receiving by `props: ['posts']`. When I even `console.log(this.posts)` in app.js file it returns `undefined`. I'm confused what the problem is:

My resources/js/app.js file:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.App = require('./App.vue');
window.addEventListener('load', function ()
{
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        render: h => h(App)
    });
});
```

My resources/js/App.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-head></app-head>
        <app-post v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id"></app-post>
        <app-foot></app-foot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Head from './components/Head.vue';
    import Foot from './components/Foot.vue';
    import Post from './components/Post.vue';

    export default {
        props: ['posts'],
        components: {
            'app-head': Head,
            'app-post': Post,
            'app-foot': Foot,
        }
    }
</script>
```

My resources/js/components/Post.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="post">
        // The post content...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [
                    {id: 1, title: 'Hello :)'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you have it interchanged. please look at my answer below and let me know if it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `props` in your component(Post) the receive the data from parent component(App).

Answer (score 0):

Few alterations are required.

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-head></app-head>
        <app-post :posts="posts"></app-post>
        <app-foot></app-foot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Head from './components/Head.vue';
    import Foot from './components/Foot.vue';
    import Post from './components/Post.vue';

    export default {

        components: {
            'app-head': Head,
            'app-post': Post,
            'app-foot': Foot,
        }, 
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [
                    {id: 1, title: 'Hello :)'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you need to prop the posts list to the component then it has to come from here. Hence, notice `data` is modified (or inserted).

Post.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
        // The post content...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['posts']
    }
</script>
```

Notice that v-for should be in the `post` component.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: As I know in template we should not iterate through an array because it is just a template but to use it in where the component is imported. No it didn't work :( BTW the tag is app-head, app-foot and app-post. that was a mistake there from me.

Comment: @kodfire can you clarify what did not work ? v-for is for iterating within a template. I did not completely understand your comment above.

Comment: can you change `app-head` to `nufa-head` as declared in `components` section. You might want to update `app-post` to `nufa-post` and `app-foot` to `nufa-foot` too. Updating the answer.

Comment: I just copied what you said in my files but it throws an error. How can I get the error content to dump it here? The problem is with ` v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id"` when I delete this part it returns `Build successful`.

Comment: Of course I have done that. I told you that I had edited the code so change in your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, just updated the answer. Can you paste the error string ? What is that you see.

Comment: The error message just pops up in task bar. How can I get its text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180440/discussion-between-82tuskers-and-kodfire).